groovy under eclipse un resolved groovy.json.JsonSlurper
I have installed the eclipse groovy plugin here
I created new groovy project and add new groovy script file to it to test.
I was trying to do json manipulation so I copied the following code to my script:
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "name": "John", "ID" : "1"}')
  
println(object.name);
println(object.ID);    

I start getting error of unresolved class path for groovy.json.JsonSlurper!! This is strange because if I run the command groovyconsole and run the script from their editor it runs fine! and I dont get this error:

I check the environment variables and the GROOVY_HOME is there and the bin folder is added to the Path env variable.
Why im getting this error? Why the plugin is failing to compile correctly despite groovy is installed and all the environment vairables are configured appropriately ? Shouldnot the plugin point to the default groovy lib based on the environment variables?
Thanks for your help.

You need to add the groovy-json dependency

OK thanks for your response. Where do I add it exactly and how ? can you put more words into this

I don't use eclipse unfortunately

I know it's not helping, but why eclipse? What's wrong with IntelliJ?

intelliJ is not free

So you need to add groovy-json as a dependency to your project.  There are two ways to do that.  If you are using a build tool like Gradle or maven you'd add it as a dependency to your project.  In gradle it might look like:
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-json:4.0.22'
}

If you aren't using a build tool you can add it to the classpath in Eclipse using the project's context menu > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries.  Then add your jar file there under User Libraries.  Here is the instructions for Eclipse:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F
